# Можно ли как-то вызвать функцию javascript после перехода по известному URL?

Tags: javascript

Можно ли как-то вызвать функцию javascript после перехода по известному URL?
Например пользователь кликает на ссылку: /user/1
страница перегружается и вызывается метод js

Comment: поясните проблему. проверять document.location в window.onload не годится  ?

Comment: Да - сгодился - спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может автор всего лишь хочет сделать так?

```
switch(location.pathname) {
    case '/user/1':
        func1();
        break;
    case '/user/2':
        func2();
        break;
    default:
        func3();
        break;
}
```